# Creating Firestore security rules that accesses the document above in the path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore collection which follows the structure outlined below

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    //allow any authenticated user to read from ComicBook
    match /MainCollection/{document} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow create:.....

      match/subcollection/{document} {
          //here i would like to use something like a get to match a field in the doc above
          allow write: if request.auth.uid == {document from above}.data.ownerID
      }
    }
```

How can i achieve this if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) to fetch any other document other than the one that's been matched by your rule.  You will also have to give you inner and outer nested rules different wildcard names:

```
match /MainCollection/{maindoc} {
  match/subcollection/{subdoc} {
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == 
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/MainCollection/$(maindoc)).data.ownerID
  }
}
```

Notice I used different wildcard names `maindoc` and `subdoc` so one variable does not mask the other.

Comment: Thanks that works I think i got confused with the matching part since i had everything as {document}